# GitLab CI: configure yaml file on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci

I have problem with test scss-lint in my project on nodejs.

[image]

**When tests reach scss-lint, it gives an error.**

**How to make sure that tests do not fall with the successful result of the test itself?**

My gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:wheezy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - test

gem_lint:
  image: ruby:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - gem install scss_lint
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - node_modules/
  only:
    - dev
  except:
    - master

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  only:
    - dev
  except:
    - master

scss-lint:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run lint:scss-lint
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  only:
    - dev
  except:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Each job you define (gem_lint, install_dependencies, and scss-lint) is run with its own context.
So your problem here is that during the last step, it doesn't find the scss-lint gem you installed because it switched its context.

You should execute all the scripts at the same time in the same context :

```
  script:
    - gem install scss_lint
    - npm install
    - npm run lint:scss-lint
```

Of course for this you need to have a docker image that has both npm and gem installed maybe you can find one on docker hub), or you can choose one (for example : ruby:latest) and add as the first script another one that would install npm :

```
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this option. 
I was able to solve my problem in a different way.

```gem_scss_lint:
  image: ruby:2.4
  stage: build
  script:
    - gem install scss_lint
    - scss-lint <file or directory>
  only:
    - dev
  except:
    - master



dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
  only:
    - dev
  except:
    - master```